# How to load kernel into memory, from an ISO

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, bootloader, bootstrapping

At compile-time I link my Assembly bootstrap together with my kernel, into an *.img file, which I then convert into an *.iso image using MagicISO. I then boot from this *.iso image.
But the problem is that I want to read the second sector of the file (the kernel) into memory at 0x1000. But I only know how to do so, with a floppy disk image, so could someone please tell me how to do so, with an *.iso?
If you need any code or anything just tell me, and I'll provide it: ).

Answer (score 2):

If your img file is a floppy image, the disc is loaded in a floppy-emulation environment. My conjecture is that you should be able to access the data just as you would on a floppy.